# Deploy and Profit - Understanding Step 10 in React Native Getting Started

Tags: android, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

After reading on how to integrate a [React Native App in an existing Android App](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html), Step 10 states:

> 10. Deploy & Profit!

I noticed it was somewhat scarce on information for the latter.

Has anyone found a solution for this step and where can I find more information?

Comment: You're asking about the deploy part, right?

Comment: I was actually interested in the profit part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 10b. "profit" is based on a meme generated from a South Park episode called *Gnomes*. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomes_(South_Park) )

The joke of the meme is that one glosses over what is needed to "profit" just assuming that, of course, there will be profit. The idea is that adding it as step in a list is all that will be needed for a successful execution. A further explanation should not be expected in the context of this meme.

Whether and exactly how you realize profit with your React Native app is probably outside the scope of the React documentation. I believe the documentation writers are relying upon your external judgment to choose an appropriate business model that will realize profit. You may at least feel encouraged by their hopeful attitude towards your endeavors.

Comment: Fascinating! Seems like there IS an answer for everything!